# Is there a way for the python package psutil to detect unmounted devices on Debian/Ubuntu and OSX

Tags: python, linux, macos, psutil

I am writing a python script that uses the psutil package to detect when a USB device is plugged into a computer. However, I would like to also detect if the device is plugged in but not mounted.

I was reading the documentation and assumed that something like `current_state = psutil.disk_partitions(all=True)` would do something like this however on further inspection it doesn't seem to.

Is there another way to get psutil to detect unmounted devices? Failing that is there a system agnostic way/package to detect if a device is plugged in but is not mounted?

Comment: @jww sorry I am unsure how this is not a programming question, I am writing a Python script using a particular library that I am having trouble with. I have edited the question to perhaps be a bit clearer.

Comment: @JulianRed, `psutil` is the name of not just a Python library but also an OS-native command-line utility package. It might reduce confusion if you asked the question in a manner that made it more explicit (in the title!) which of these you were asking about (granted, the edits have already helped!).

Comment: ...that said, what you're asking for isn't all that trivial. Determining that something is "plugged in and not mounted" means interrogating each USB device's class -- if it's not USB storage, for instance, then you don't want to mount it. And devices can offer endpoints with multiple classes -- if a keyboard has a USB storage mountpoint with drivers, do you really want to detect it as unmounted?

Comment: ...I suppose you could look for unmounted block devices; that makes the decision around which devices we care about one that the OS is responsible for. OTOH, if you want to limit that to USB-backed unmounted block devices, then that means still more OS-specific wiring that needs to be implemented, so I'm not really particularly surprising at any library not having done the heavy lifting already.

Comment: (I could write an answer that did this -- without `psutil`, directly interrogating sysfs -- on Linux pretty easily, but MacOS I don't know the equivalent interfaces for).

Comment: I noticed the library seems to offer an unmounted flag for Windows, but not being a Windows user that was little help. I'm neither a OSX or Linux expert when it comes to these things but I imagine I could successfully port a Linux solution to OSX.

Comment: It might not be that easy -- sysfs is *very* Linux-specific -- but if you're comfortable with that, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Listing unmounted block devices is OS-dependent: The mechanism for doing so is not common between MacOS and Linux, and presently, the `psutil` library does not implement an abstraction layer over those differentes.

#### Listing All Block Devices On Linux

The following iterator will yield a list of block devices on Linux, excluding those which have partitions (for which you presumably only want to check whether the partitions themselves are mounted), such that the result can be compared against the list of devices attached to mount points:

```
import glob

def linux_block_devices():
    for blockdev_stat in glob.glob('/sys/block/*/stat'):
        blockdev_dir = blockdev_stat.rsplit('/', 1)[0]
        found_parts = False
        for part_stat in glob.glob(blockdev_dir + '/*/stat'):
            yield blockdev_stat.rsplit('/', 2)[-2]
            found_parts = True
        if not found_parts:
            yield blockdev_dir.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

#### Listing All Block Devices On MacOS

On MacOS, I'm unaware of an interface intended for programmatic use exposed to Python -- you might end up parsing command-line output, as the following:

```
import subprocess, re

def mac_block_devices():
    output = subprocess.check_output(['diskutil', 'list'])
    return re.findall('^\s+\d+:.*\s(disk\S*)$', output, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

...this one is cruder, inasmuch as it doesn't exclude devices that have children; consider that an exercise for the reader.

#### Combining Either Of The Above With `psutil`

```
import os, psutil

all_block_devices = set(
  linux_block_devices() if os.path.exists('/sys') else mac_block_devices()
)
used_block_devices = set(
    (p.device.replace('/dev/', '') for p in psutil.disk_partitions())
)
unused_block_devices = all_block_devices - used_block_devices
```

The above will give you a list of unused block devices on either OS -- akin to `set(['sdb1', 'sdc1']) on Linux, or set(['disk3', 'disk4s1'])` on MacOS.

Note that this is "unused" in the sense of "not used in the mount table". There are several other ways a block device can be used without being present in the mount table (direct raw access by application code; swap partition use; presence in device-mapper or backing for logical-volume mechanisms; etc), and detecting all these would require a great deal of wiring for either OS.

Answer (score -1):

I have recently solved this problem on OSX and potentially on *nix as well (pending further testing) using `hidapi`. An example of how I used it is included below:

```
import hid
import pprint

hid_state = hid.enumerate()
pprint.pprint(hid_state)
```

The output is as follows:

```
[ {'interface_number': -1,
'manufacturer_string': 'Apple Inc.',
'path':     b'IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14/X'
          b'HC1@14000000/HS12@14400000/Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@14'
          b'400000/Apple Internal Keyboard@0/AppleUSBTCKeyboard@14400000,0',
  'product_id': 610,
  'product_string': 'Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad',
  'release_number': 549,
  'serial_number': '',
  'usage': 6,
  'usage_page': 1,
  'vendor_id': 1452},
 {'interface_number': -1,
  'manufacturer_string': 'Apple Inc.',
  'path': b'IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14/X'
          b'HC1@14000000/HS12@14400000/Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@14'
          b'400000/Touchpad@1/AppleUSBMultitouchDriver@14400000,1',
  'product_id': 610,
  'product_string': 'Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad',
  'release_number': 549,
  'serial_number': '',
  'usage': 1,
  'usage_page': 65280,
  'vendor_id': 1452},
 {'interface_number': -1,
  'manufacturer_string': 'Apple Inc.',
  'path': b'IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14/X'
          b'HC1@14000000/HS12@14400000/Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@14'
          b'400000/Touchpad@2/AppleUSBTCButtons@14400000,2',
  'product_id': 610,
  'product_string': 'Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad',
  'release_number': 549,
  'serial_number': '',
  'usage': 2,
  'usage_page': 1,
  'vendor_id': 1452},
 {'interface_number': -1,
  'manufacturer_string': '',
  'path': b'IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/PEG1@1,1/'
          b'IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@3/IOPP/UPS0@0/IOPP/pci-bridge@0/IOPP/pci1b'
          b'73,1100@0/AppleUSBXHCIFL1100@00000000/AppleUSB20XHCIPort@0040000'
          b'0/USB Keyboard@00400000/IOUSBHostInterface@1/IOUSBHostHIDDevice@'
          b'00400000,1',
  'product_id': 617,
  'product_string': 'USB Keyboard',
  'release_number': 4368,
  'serial_number': '',
  'usage': 1,
  'usage_page': 12,
  'vendor_id': 1241},
 {'interface_number': -1,
  'manufacturer_string': '',
  'path': b'IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/HDEF@1B/A'
          b'ppleHDAController@1B/IOHDACodecDevice@1B,0/IOHDACodecDriver/IOHD'
          b'ACodecFunction@1B,0,1/AppleHDACodecGeneric/AppleHDADriver/AppleM'
          b'ikeyHIDDriver',
  'product_id': 0,
  'product_string': 'Apple Mikey HID Driver',
  'release_number': 0,
  'serial_number': '',
  'usage': 1,
  'usage_page': 12,
  'vendor_id': 0}]
```

This example has been reduced for brevity, however one problem faced was multiple entries for the same device where only the path is slightly different, an example is shown below:

```
'path': b'IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14/X'
b'HC1@14000000/HS12@14400000/Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@14'
b'400000/Touchpad@2/AppleUSBTCButtons@14400000,2',
```

vs.

```
'path': b'IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14/X'
b'HC1@14000000/HS12@14400000/Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad@14'
b'400000/Apple Internal Keyboard@0/AppleUSBTCKeyboard@14400000,0',
```

I was able to remove these duplicates (as many only ended with a different ",number") by sorting the list of dicts using the path value minus the last characters, like as follows:

```
list({str(v['path'][:-2]): v for v in r}.values())
```

As I have mentioned I still need to do testing on *nix, however, I can say it has done a good job of picking up HID devices such as mice and keyboards on OSX, I will need to determine if it is able to pick up malicious HID devices such as USB Rubber Duckies but signs look good.